# facing issue while converting spring integration based web services to spring boot

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-boot, spring-integration

I would like to convert the Spring Integration based web services to Spring Boot Application.

My application is developed using spring integration web services.
I want to convert that existed application into spring boot.I have tried to find many demos. No demo is available in online.

While converting I was facing this issue.

My Soap meesage response after submitting the request is as follows:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">No adapter for endpoint [countryGateway]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Startup of the application is given below

Application.Java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Spring configuration is as below

Sample-context.xml

```
    <bean id="payloadMapping"
        class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop
                    key="{http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service}getCountryRequest">countryGateway</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="countryRequestChannel"></int:channel>
    <int:channel id="countryResponseChannel"></int:channel>
    <int:channel id="countryErrorChannel"></int:channel>

    <int-ws:inbound-gateway id="countryGateway"
        error-channel="countryErrorChannel" request-channel="countryRequestChannel"
        reply-channel="countryResponseChannel"  />

        <int:service-activator input-channel="countryRequestChannel" output-channel="countryResponseChannel" method="hello" ref="sampleActivator"></int:service-activator>
    <bean id="sampleActivator" class="com.sample.country.SampleValidate"></bean>
```

Maven configuration is as below

POM.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample.country</groupId>
    <artifactId>springbootsample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <!-- Adding the dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- To support web services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xom</groupId>
            <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Web service configuration that i used is as given below

WebServiceConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }
    @Bean(name = "countries")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CountriesPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("countries.xsd"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you referencing the `Sample-context.xml` anywhere.

Try adding

```
@ImportResource("Sample-context.ml")
```

to the `Application` class.

**EDIT**

`@EnableWs` doesn't add a `MessageEndpointAdapter`, just a `MethodEndpointAdapter`.

This works...

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
@ImportResource("Sample-context.xml")
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(MessageDispatcherServlet servlet) {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageDispatcherServlet servlet() {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return servlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageEndpointAdapter adapter() {
        return new MessageEndpointAdapter();
    }

    @Bean(name = "countries")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CountriesPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("countries.xsd"));
    }

}
```

Comment: After adding also Same error is coming.Issue is not get resolved